# How to handle "no attribute 'setCurrentText'" using the PySide Qt QComboBox

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qcombobox

When trying to use addItem on a Qt QComboBox using PySide I am getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QComboBox' object has no attribute 'setCurrentText'

How can one use a ComboBox if the addItem method results in an error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was causing the error but I was able to make use of the QComboBox by using an explicit model instead.

Psuedocode:

```
model = QStandardItemModel(comboBox)
item1 = QStandardItem( "item1" )
item2 = QStandardItem( "item2" )
model.appendRow(item1) 
model.appendRow(item2)
comboBox.setModel(model)
```